# QML: Cannot access signal

Tags: qt, qml

I just started out with Qt. I've written a little QML-Button, and there's a problem which drives me crazy. I just can't get it to work.

```
// import QtQuick 1.0 // to target S60 5th Edition or Maemo 5
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
id: bluebutton
property alias labeltext: label.text
signal pressed()

width: 130
height: 40
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "darkblue"
        Text {
            id: label
            scale: 2
            color: "white"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: mousefield
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: bluebutton.pressed() //.pressed() doesn't appear in the suggestions
        }
    }
}
```

So here's the problem: 
apparently, i cant refer to *any* kind of signal defined in the Item-Element. I tried to refer to the property "labeltext" (bluebutton.labeltext) and it worked. But i can't refer to pressed() ! Why? Needless to say, the Button doesn't work...

```
Rectangle {
    width: 250
    height: 200
    color: "lightblue"

    Button {
        labeltext: "Quit"
        onPressed: Qt.quit
    }
}
```

Does anybody know whats going on?

---

EDIT: Ok, signals do work... -.-
But Qt.quit doesn't work for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution: 
I forgot braces...

*wrong:* Qt.quit
*right:* Qt.quit()

There you go. Conclusion: Always check if you forgot braces =D

Comment: The appöication output in QtCreator is quiet useful for debugging stuff like this. Normally you can find there some error message.